# Convert index match formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, index-match

I am trying to convert this formula to VBA Code but have no idea how to.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$10,MATCH($G3&I$2,$B$3:$B$10&$D$3:$D$10,0)),"")
```

Comment: What do you expect from `MATCH($G3&I$2,$B$3:$B$10&$D$3:$D$10,0)`? Especially this part: `$B$3:$B$10&$D$3:$D$10`. To find a match in the two concatenated columns ranges? Does the formula you use ever return anything than an empty string? Please, try the `Match` part separately...

Comment: Why do you want it in VBA and how do you intend to use it? I'd have thought `Evaluate` would be the *simplest* method.

Comment: G3 would be the employee id while I2 is the header name. The header name can be found in a fieldname column in a source file. What i want to achieve is to get a specific data from a fieldvalue column once it matches the employee id and fieldname from the source file.

Comment: I'd love to share a sample file but am not allowed to paste one here. If you have an email ad where I can send the sample file then that would be of ease.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following

```
Dim fndRng as Range
set firstAddr as String

' Update this to your sheet reference
With ActiveSheet
    set fndRng = .Range("B3:B10").find(Range("G3").Value2)
    If Not fndRng is nothing then
        firstAddr = fndRng.Address
        Do
            If fndRng.Offset(0,2).Value2 = .Range("I2").Value2 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set fndRng = .Range("B3:B10").FindNext(fndRng)
        Loop Until fndRng is Nothing or fndRng.Address = firstAddr
    
        MsgBox fndRng.Address & ": " & fndRng.Offset(0, 3).Value2
    end if
End With
```